# Adding to unsigned and signed binary integers

Tags: binary, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

I was wondering if someone can explain to me what happens when we add binary numbers.

Say we have 4 bits, 0b1111 and we add 1 to 0b1111. I think the binary encoding should be 0b10000; however, since there are only 4 bits the bits will change to 0b0000.

I was wondering why this happens, is it because there's not enough space? How would we add 1 to it if 0b1111 was a signed integer?

Comment: this is cause overflow, You cant show the number 8 with 3 bits/4 bit sign

Comment: This question may need a chapter to elaborate. If you want to know the ins and outs, check [Unsigned and Signed Integers](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/13.html) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `0b1111` is an unsigned 4 bit value, with 4 bit storage, it has a value of 15. Adding 1 to it, will give you 16, which cannot be stored in 4 bits. The bits roll over and `0b0000` is stored, giving you a result of 0.

Now, if `0b1111` is a signed 4 bit value, with 4 bit storage.  it is generally stored in the two's complement representation. It has a range of -8 to +7. `0b1111` will give you -1. (See [here](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/tctod.html) on how to convert.) Adding one to that gives you 0.